# pyuic5 not giving any output

Tags: python, pyqt5, converters, pyuic

I tried to convert my **.ui** file made from PyQt5 Designer to a **.py** file. But when I run the command `pyuic5 -x gui_calculator.ui -o gui_cal.py` it gives nothing as output and there is no file created in the directory. Python version - 3.10.0b4[image]

when I run the command `pyuic5` alone the same happens. When the command `where pyuic5` ran it shows `C:\Users\2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyuic5.exe`.

Comment: Can you try these 2 commands: `pyuic5` alone and `where pyuic5`?

Comment: @zigma12 now check the question

Comment: @ekhumoro what do you mean by *isn't installed in a folder on your path.*

Comment: @Savithu What is the output of `echo %PATH%`? Also, what does `pyuic5 -h` show?

Comment: @ekhumoro I am not a win user but I remember windows system is globally case insensitive. So whatever the case the result is the same. `where pyuic5` proves this is not a PATH issue

Comment: @Savithu can you try without `-x` and/or with `--debug` option. Maybe it will give you some output. This link is your friend: https://manpages.org/pyuic5

Comment: Sorry to ask but have you double checked `gui_cal.py` is not created? The base name is different from the input file!!

Comment: @zigma12 Yeah, I just thought of that a few minutes ago - it's been so long since I used windows, that I completely forgot about this "feature". It seems the OP just isn't looking in the right place for the output file.